# Running a .sh script with crontab

Tags: scripting, cron, oracle-database, oracle

I have a file named `diario.sh` that I run manually using `./diario.sh`

The script file contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/etapa/Scripts
echo "@CDRS_ETAPATOTAL.sql" | sqlplus -s ooperadores/ooperadores@OOPERADORES | while read output;
do
echo $output
done
```

When I run it manually works fine but when I try to run it using `crontab` I get the following error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
<proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]

ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

The `crontab` entry is the following:

```
10 * * * * /home/etapa/Scripts/diario.sh > /home/etapa/Scripts/diario.log 2>&1
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some environment variables are not populated when you're running this script from cron. You could solve it by sourcing (`. /path/name`) the appropriate files, e.g.

```
#! /bin/bash
. /home/etapa/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!!